# jQuery one event at a time

Tags: jquery

I am using fadeOut and fadeIn through change() event.  Problem is you can chose both options quickly and end up with both event occuring at the same time.  How do I make it so only 1 event occurs and when that event is finished then the second event is allowed to happen should user select the option?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  .box1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
  }
  .box2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #0f0;
    display: none;
  }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/

          $(document).on('change', 'input[name=all]', function(){

           var which = $(this).attr('id');
           if (which =='b'){
              $('.box1').fadeOut(function(){ $('.box2').fadeIn(); });
           }
           else
           {
             //$('.check_box_holder_for_playlist_items').show();
              $('.box2').fadeOut(function(){ $('.box1').fadeIn(); });
           }

           });
  /*]]>*/
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="test" action="http://">
<label><input type="radio" name="all" value="1" id="a" checked="checked" /> Show box 1</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="all" value="2" id="b" /> Show box 2</label><br />
</form>
<div class="box1"> first box </div>
<div class="box2"> second box </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a stop in the script

[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp9jg/1/)

```
       $(document).on('change', 'input[name=all]', function(){

       var which = $(this).attr('id');
       if (which =='b'){
          $('.box1').stop().fadeOut(function(){ $('.box2').stop().fadeIn(); });
       }
       else
       {
         //$('.check_box_holder_for_playlist_items').show();
          $('.box2').stop().fadeOut(function(){ $('.box1').stop().fadeIn(); });
       }

       });
```

Here I use a `.fadeToggle();`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp9jg/6/)

```
      $(document).on('change', 'input[name=all]', function(){

      $('.toggle').stop().fadeToggle(500);

      });
```

Comment: Ok, did that and it's almost there.  Now if you hit both options quickly, it will stop in the middle and have a bit of transparency.  Is there a function that will allow the current event to finish but not start the next event until the first event is finished?

Comment: @simianIII As of now, if you hit the first, then hit the second, it stops the first and starts the second. Isn't this what you were looking for? You can't have it two ways, either you want the animation to finish, or you want it to stop and start the other animation. If you want it to finish before the next one starts, you will end up accumulating animations as you had originally.

Comment: You could always declare absolute position on the box and just toggle the visibility.

Comment: @VIDesigns, great Idea... add the absolute positioning.  FYI, yes it works perfectly as is in some of the browsers... On my Firefox though, it continued as before, able to run both events simultaneously.  I think I might have some odd settings on my browswer though because I couldn't recreate it elsewhere.

Comment: I tried to upvote you but it said I didn't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @simianIII Glad to hear man! IE never performs the fades that well and overall, each browser has its quirks.  It would be a miracle when everything we do renders right in all browsers! haha. Thanks for accepting my answer and don't worry about the up-vote, when you get a bunch of rep points, don't forget about the little guy and come back to up-vote me ;)